# Clonezilla saving files to a directory, but I want to save the files to a different drive

Tags: hard-drive, clonezilla

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 at the moment.

I'm using [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php) ([more documentation](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-usage/general-live-use.php)) to save images. The images are saved within a folder I created, titled "images", on the same drive where the operating system resides, and there's not enough space to save all the images.

I've done this before, but it's been years. The computer running Ubuntu has a second hard drive that is nearly 1 TB in size, and I want to have that hard drive be used as the destination for the images.

How is that done again?